# Is there a non-compact open subset of the ring of $p$-adic intergers $\Bbb{Z}_p, p$ a prime?

Tags: general-topology, p-adic-number-theory

Can anyone give me some idea? I cant find it at all.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is Hausdorff (as a metric space), so a compact subset has to be closed. Can you find an open subset that is not closed?

Comment: It might be easer to find a closed set that isn't open and then take its complement.

Comment: Indeed, @Andreas :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try $\mathbf Z_p - \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The ring of $p$-adic integers is compact Hausdorff. Suppose every open subset is compact, hence closed. Then every closed subset would be open, so any singleton would be open and the topology would be discrete.